# Code window for websites

Tags: html, web

I am the webmaster from [www.idoodler.de](http://www.idoodler.de), I started a Raspberry Pi how to site. The site contains Python, Ruby, Shell Script… scripts. 
My question: Is is there a HTML code that formats the code like in Stackoverflow?

Like this:

```
import os

os.system(command)
```

it would be even better if the window can add colors to the different types of code.

It would be very cool if someone can tell me either how to make such a HTML view or a link to a site that explains how to achieve this. And btw I am using Sandvox for Mac to create the website, so I am able to use Sandvox plugins too.

Thanks David from Germany

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For highlighting code in HTML you can use [highlight.js](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/). All you have to do is wrap your code in `<pre><code>` tags and include the JS file:

```
<pre><code> some code in here </code></pre>
```

Highlight.js will then try to recognize, which language was used and apply the highlighting accordingly.

Comment: OK, this looks awesome. I make my costume highlight.js and uploaded it to my server, I am using Sandvox (I don't know if you know it but it is great). What do you mean with incloude the JS file, must I link to it, or must I put some code in the header of the site? I am using HTML windows for each code, so I may have to add the code to every HTML window, right?

Comment: The [github repo](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js) shows the basic usage. Basically yes, you have to put those 3 lines into every HTML file, where you want to have highlighting.